# c++ a heap has been corrupted error when running the program

Tags: c++

I have the following program and every time I'm running it sometimes (most of the times) I'm getting heap corruption error

I can't put my finger where its happenning since every run it pops in different place on my program.

can someone put some light on it please?

P.S heap corruption also pop when I'm trying to free p

Thanks in advance

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_OF_PLAYERS = 10;
const int SIZE = 100;

struct player_t {
    char *name;
    int numOfShirt;
};
struct team_t {
    char *nameOfTeam;
    int maxOfPlayers;
    int numOfPlayers;
    player_t *players;

};

void readPlayer(player_t *player);
void initTeam(team_t *team);
void addPlayer(team_t *team);
void printTeam(team_t *team);
void freeAll(team_t *team);
player_t** getAllPlayersStartWithA(team_t *team);
void printAteam(player_t **p);

int main()
{
    team_t t;
    player_t **p;
    initTeam(&t);
    addPlayer(&t);
    addPlayer(&t);
    printTeam(&t);
    p = getAllPlayersStartWithA(&t);
    if (p[0] != NULL)
        printAteam(p);
    system("pause");
    freeAll(&t);
    //delete[] p;
}

void readPlayer(player_t *player)
{
    char name[SIZE];
    cout << " please enter the name of the player " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << " please enter the num of the shirt " << endl;
    cin >> player->numOfShirt;
    int size = strlen(name);
    char *res = new char[size + 2];
    strcpy(res, name);
    player->name = res;
}
void initTeam(team_t *team)
{

    char name[SIZE];

    // get the team name
    cout << " please enter your team name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    // get the name length
    int size = strlen(name);
    // allocate new array with length size
    team->nameOfTeam = new char[size + 1];
    // copy the string to the new array
    strcpy(team->nameOfTeam, name);

    // get the number of max players
    cout << "please enter the number of the max players on your team" << endl;
    cin >> team->maxOfPlayers;

    // create new players array
    player_t *players = new player_t[team->maxOfPlayers];
    // initial the players array
    for (int i = 0; i < team->maxOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        players[i] = { 0 };
    }
    //bind the array to team
    team->players = players;

    // set current players to 0
    team->numOfPlayers = 0;

}
void addPlayer(team_t *team)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < team->maxOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        if (team->players[i].name == NULL)
        {
            readPlayer(team->players + i);
            break;
        }
    }

}
void printTeam(team_t *team)
{

    cout << "Team name: ";
    cout << team->nameOfTeam << endl;

    cout << "Max Number of players in team: ";
    cout << team->maxOfPlayers << endl;

    cout << "Current number of players in team: ";
    cout << team->numOfPlayers << endl;

    cout << "Team Players:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < team->maxOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        if (team->players[i].name)
        {
            cout << "Player name: ";
            cout << team->players[i].name;
            cout << ", ";
            cout << "Player shirt: ";
            cout << team->players[i].numOfShirt << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void freeAll(team_t *team)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < team->maxOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        if ((team->players + i)->name != NULL)
            delete[](team->players + i)->name;
    }

    delete[] team->players;
}
player_t** getAllPlayersStartWithA(team_t *team)
{
    int sum = 0, position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; team->players[i].name != NULL; i++)
    {
        if (team->players[i].name[0] == 'a' || team->players[i].name[0] == 'A')
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }

    player_t **p = new player_t*[sum + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < team->maxOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        p[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; team->players[i].name != NULL; i++)
    {
        if (team->players[i].name[0] == 'a')
        {
            p[position++] = team->players + i;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
void printAteam(player_t **p)
{
    cout << "Players start with 'A': " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; p[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        cout << "Player name: ";
        cout << (p[i]->name);
        cout << ", ";
        cout << "Player shirt: ";
        cout << (p[i]->numOfShirt) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though, heap corruption errors are difficult to diagnose (Welcome to C++!), did you try **stepping through** your code with a debugger, while investigating the values of the variables? EDIT: why are you using `char*` instead of `std::string` inside your `struct`s? Why are you passing pointers to your objects, to your functions, instead of references?

Comment: you're programming with c++, so make your life easier with classes and STL-container. Using raw pointer is in the most cases a bad idea and makes you a lot of trouble. Just use them when you have legitimate reasons.

Comment: One potential problem is here `for (int i = 0; team->players[i].name != NULL; i++)`. If the team has a full set of players, none of them will have an empty name.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes I did step by step debug and heap corruption error pop in different places every time, sometimes the program ran without errors.
I'm using char* because it's school work and they defined the structs so I cannot change it.

Comment: @Soeren
as I mention, it's a school ex and I can't use classes. I have strict rules

Comment: @Brec So you should change your teacher, since he is teaching C as C++ (despite the use of `cin`). And that's why I mentioned, that you should pay close attention to the values of the variables, since the values of those, can give you hints when code starts to do something, that you didn't expect.

Comment: @Brec *it's a school ex and I can't use classes.* -- Then you are learning `C` with hardly any `C++` being used.  Also, does your "teacher" give points for memory leaks?  Your code is full of them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have not reviewed the whole code, but there are tools available that can help you in this situation that track the usage of memory and indicate if something went wrong. One example is valgrind that is at least available for Linux environments. Anyway, this tool allowed me to find at least one bug in your code as follows.

1. Compile with debug information. If you are using gcc, use the -g command line flag e.g.

   ```
   g++ foo.cpp -g -o foo -std=gnu++11
   ```
2. Run with valgrind

   ```
   valgrind ./foo
   ```
3. Look at the output

   ```
   ==6423== Memcheck, a memory error detector
   ==6423== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
   ==6423== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
   ==6423== Command: ./foo
   ==6423== 
    please enter your team name
   sdfads
   please enter the number of the max players on your team
   3
    please enter the name of the player 
   efwf
    please enter the num of the shirt 
   5
    please enter the name of the player 
   dsfdsa
    please enter the num of the shirt 
   3
   Team name: sdfads
   Max Number of players in team: 3
   Current number of players in team: 0
   Team Players:
   Player name: efwf, Player shirt: 5
   Player name: dsfdsa, Player shirt: 3

   ==6423== Invalid write of size 8
   ==6423==    at 0x4011FF: getAllPlayersStartWithA(team_t*) (foo.cpp:155)
   ==6423==    by 0x400C08: main (foo.cpp:38)
   ==6423==  Address 0x5ab6668 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
   ==6423==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   ==6423==    by 0x4011CC: getAllPlayersStartWithA(team_t*) (foo.cpp:151)
   ==6423==    by 0x400C08: main (foo.cpp:38)
   ==6423== 
   ==6423== 
   ==6423== HEAP SUMMARY:
   ==6423==     in use at exit: 72,719 bytes in 3 blocks
   ==6423==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 5 frees, 74,829 bytes allocated
   ==6423== 
   ==6423== LEAK SUMMARY:
   ==6423==    definitely lost: 15 bytes in 2 blocks
   ==6423==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   ==6423==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   ==6423==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
   ==6423==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   ==6423== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
   ==6423== 
   ==6423== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
   ==6423== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
   ```
4. Apparently you have a problem in line 155 according to this output

   ```
   ==6423== Invalid write of size 8
   ==6423==    at 0x4011FF: getAllPlayersStartWithA(team_t*) (foo.cpp:155)
   ```

   And if we look closer, we see the following:

   ```
   player_t **p = new player_t*[sum + 1];
   for (int i = 0; i < team->maxOfPlayers; i++)
   {
        p[i] = NULL;
   }
   ```

   You create an array of size sum+1, but iterate over it up to team->maxOfPlayers that might or might not be the same. This means you write to some memory outside of the array that you want to modify and therefore you write somewhere in the heap where you should not (leading to a heap corruption).

This is at least one problem. Repeat 1.-4. until valgrind has nothing else to complain about.

Comment: Just one comment: not all people are compiling their C++ with g++, nor does all people are using platform compatible with valgrind. Since OP didn't describe the platform they are using, the answer should either: contain platform-independent, problem solving suggestion, or not contain this, preference-based suggestion.

Comment: I have to admit that I am not aware of the tool available e.g. in Visual Studio for this, but I would suggest that someone edits the answer (or posts another one) describing the way there. Using such tools helps a lot, so why should we avoid posting such answers? However, I will edit the answer indicating the platform.

Comment: Solved my problem, 
can you please guide me to tutorial that explain how to debug like this?

Comment: You can find one here http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html and another one here http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/ The start is not so easy, especially if you have never worked with command line tools and very much depends on your programming environment as it was pointed out before, but it is worth the effort and really saves time in the long run.

Comment: I'm using an older Mac OSX (10.9), which cannot run a stable version of Valgrind unfortunately. I'm curious whether there is something that I could use to solve the same problem.

Comment: There are also modules called AddressSanitizer in both gcc (enable with 
-fsanitize=address) and clang, maybe they are available for Mac OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take more care with how you're accessing arrays and keeping track of the sizes of them.

As a comment already pointed out, `for (int i = 0; team->players[i].name != NULL; i++)` is asking for trouble. You should ensure that the loop is constrained by something, either the total number of entries in the `players` array (presumably `maxOfPlayers`) or the current number of valid players which seems like it should be `numOfPlayers`. However your code never actually increments `numOfPlayers` when adding new entries.

The following code from `getAllPlayersStartWithA` is also a problem:

```
player_t **p = new player_t*[sum + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < team->maxOfPlayers; i++)
{
    p[i] = NULL;
}
```

The `sum + 1` can easily be much less than `maxOfPlayers`. In that case the for loop will overwrite memory beyond the end of the array. This could very well be the cause of your current heap corruption error.